# vlookup with effective date/rate

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm trying to write a vlookup formula that will

1). check for duplicates in the list and

2). if there is a duplicate, then check the dates, and pull the correct rate in the vlookup return value, depending on the date.

So for example, if Michael has a rate of $100 per hour for 7/1/2017, I can assume this is his rate until noted otherwise with an additional line. On 7/3/2017 his rate changes to $120. So for hours worked on 7/1/2017 and 7/2/2017, the rate should be $100, but on 7/3/2017 and on, the rate should be $120, or until a new line is added for Michael indicating a new rate on a specific date.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks!

[image: Column E "Rates" should pull in the effective rate from the "Effective Rate" tab, based on the name and date/date range]

[image: This is where the rates are stored and additional lines will be added when new rates are needed]

Comment: Is your lookup table reliably sorted by name then date?

Comment: yes, it will always be AtoZ for names and then AtoZ for dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this if you sort by name and by date **descending**

[image]

Note it's an array formula so you need to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with MAXIFS(). The multiple conditions lets you find the multiple conditions, but MAXIFS() will always return an individual value unlike SUMIFS or COUNTIFS. Place hte formula in cell F2 and fill it down

```
=MAXIFS('Effective Rate'!$C:$C,'Effective Rate'!$A:$A,A2,'Effective Rate'!$B:$B,"<="&B2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to use this formula. My excel (2016) doesn't seem to recognize the maxifs function. Could you tell me where this formula is supposed to go?

Comment: maxifs is available in 2016 (and only in 2016).

Comment: I would place this in cell F2 and fill it down.